# Netbeans says javafx.scene.layout.ButtonBar does not exist using jdk1.8

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I'm pretty new to Java and very new to JavaFX, SceneBuilder and Netbeans. I already have NetBeans set to use JDK 1.8. While following [a tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/) for JavaFX I created a scene in SceneBuilder 9.0.1 using a ButtonBar, and when viewing that FXML document in NetBeans I get a message that says "Class javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar does not exist." I've tried importing that class by using:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar>
```

or

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.*>
```

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" fx:controller="ch.makery.address.model.PersonOverviewController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@personoverview.css" />
    </stylesheets>
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="137.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="124.0" layoutY="6.0" text="Person Details" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="5.0" />
                  <ButtonBar layoutX="154.0" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                    <buttons>
                      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
                    </buttons>
                  </ButtonBar>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

When trying to run this I get a popup window from Netbeans asking me to select a class but there aren't any classes to select.

Sorry if this has already been answered, I searched and couldn't find anything that worked.

Thank for any help/tips/advice in advance!

Comment: Which is your JDK version? Is NetBeans using the same JDK version?

Comment: Get `Java 9` or `SceneBuilder 8.4.1`. This may solve your problem.

Comment: Why does the title say `javafx.scene.layout.ButtonBar`?

Comment: Yeah, switching to JDK 8 solved it, thanks for the help